# How to copy an One2many field in an onchange method and modify it?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

I think I did this a thousand times, but today I am not able to achieve it and have a lot of doubts.

**PURPOSE**

I need to copy the records of an *One2many* field to my *One2many* field, but changing the value of a column. This action must be performed in an *onchange* method.

**SCENARIO**

I am in the model `mrp.bom`. It has an *One2many* field named `bom_line_ids`. It also has the *Many2one* field named `product_id`.

Each time `product_id` changes, I have to fill in automatically the `bom_line_ids` of the current bill of materials record, taking the data from the `bom_line_ids` field of other bill of materials. But these records will not be exactly the same, I need to modify a column.

**EXAMPLE**

In an *onchange* method, I need to copy the recordset `mrp.bom.line(10, 11)` to my *One2many* field, but in my *One2many* field both records will have the field `line_type` with the value `'standard'` (it does not matter the `line_type` value of the source records).

**MY ATTEMPT**

I tried a lot of things. The closest attempt to the solution was this one. But this fails when the current bill of materials record has not been saved in the database yet, because of `_origin`. The error says that `bom_id` is NULL and it is mandatory... The problem is that if I do not write `_origin`, that error raises always, it does not matter if the current bill of material already exists or not. And if I remove the `bom_id` key from the `default` dictionary, the new lines are added to the source *One2many* instead of mine...

```
@api.onchange('product_id')
def onchange_product_id(self):
    if self.product_id and \
       self.product_id.product_tmpl_id.bom_ids:
        # Following lines are only for taking the source BoM
        bom_ids = self.product_id.product_tmpl_id.bom_ids.filtered(
            lambda r: not r.product_id)
        bom_id = bom_ids[0] if bom_ids else False
        # Following lines are for doing the copy
        new_lines = self.env['mrp.bom.line']
        for line in bom_id.bom_line_ids:
            new_lines += line.copy(default={
                'bom_id': self._origin.id,
                'line_type': 'standard',
            })
        self.bom_line_ids = [(6, 0, new_lines.ids)]
```

**CONCLUSION**

I think I am making this complexer than it is, there must be some easier solution... Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with another options like add "active" field in bom.line object.

With that you can disable your previous bom line and add new bom lines in onchange method without disturb any other flow.

PS: I haven't try it.

**EDIT:**

Browse lines and prepare a list `(0, 0,  { values })` to update one2many field.

```
@api.onchange('product_id')
def onchange_product_id(self):
    if self.product_id and \
       self.product_id.product_tmpl_id.bom_ids:
        bom_ids = self.product_id.product_tmpl_id.bom_ids.filtered(
            lambda r: not r.product_id)
        bom_id = bom_ids[0] if bom_ids else False
        new_lines = []
        for line in bom_id.bom_line_ids:
            vals = line.read()[0]
            vals.update({
                'line_type': 'standard',
            })
            vals.pop('bom_id', False)
            new_lines.append((0, 0, vals))
        self.bom_line_ids = new_lines
```

Comment: Hi Odedra, I do not want to disable previous BoM lines (with previous lines I guess you mean source lines), because they must exist and be visible. I only want to copy those lines to my *One2many* field, and then (or at the same time), modify a field value in each copied record. The source lines must keep being visible with the old data, the new lines must be a copy of those with the field value changed, but all must be active.

Comment: Ah. Got it. How about not use copy() method and use `(0, 0,  { values }) ` format to update one2many field. Now you can update values as per your needed. I think these will fix your problem.

Comment: Ok, I'll try, but, how would you fill in `values` (since it must be a dictionary with all the fields of the source line as keys and all their values -except for one- as the key values). Would you use `search_read` method for this or other way? I mean that you have to convert the source line (a `mrp.bom.line` object) into a dictionary, then update that dictionary (to modify the field I want to change) and then perform the `(0, 0, values_dict)` operation. How would you do the conversion?

Comment: Finally I did it, I am going to edit your answer to show the code, but your idea works.